# Count frequency of terms in vector of strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(c("A","B","A,B","","A,C,D"))
```

What I would like to do is count the frequency of each individual term and return a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    A    3
    B    2
    C    1
```

I'm familiar with the various methods for splitting these strings into columns in my dataframe such as cSplit, read.table, etc., but that's not ideal since I have hundreds of distinct values that I need to count.

Thank you!

Comment: `table(unlist(strsplit(c("A","B","A,B","","A,C,D"), ",")))`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution form David. Thanks!

```
table(unlist(strsplit(c("A","B","A,B","","A,C,D"), ",")))
```